# Lollipop development for OnePlus One

Tags: android

Need help wit compiling rom for Oneplus one - Lollipop version
Please I need serious help

I am trying to build lollipop for oneplus one.
I have followed multiple guides to get this correct.

```
`However I am stuck at navendu@navendu:~/bin/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ make -j16
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_bacon
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.16.0-25-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.10-utopic
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=LRX21M
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
build/core/dex_preopt.mk:47: *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop.

However if i use "sudo make -j 16"
I get this 
Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 15

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_bacon
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.16.0-25-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.10-utopic
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=LRX21M
OUT_DIR=out
    ============================================

    navendu@navendu:~/bin/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ sudo make -j16
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.16.0-25-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.10-utopic
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=LRX21M
OUT_DIR=out 
    ============================================
Checking build tools versions...
```

What happens is the target product and everything changes so the output is a generic build.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use the 'lunch' command first before 'make' command to lock to target product (device code) you want to build with.
like:

```
lunch bacon
```

and then
    make -j16
and also I think you should better reduce the -jX number so the computer will not lag up. Like use j4.

I really hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your dependencies for what ROM you intend on building. Such as trying to build for Paranoid Android, have your pa dependencies set with what repositories your using. If those are both set correctly, you shouldn't have an issue.

./rom-build.sh bacon